Adding tag for specific Docker image
I am using a pipeline (MainPipeline) which triggers the next one (DependantPipeline).
During the DependantPipeline execution on Azure DevOps I see the error on Terraform Plan step during the fetching Docker image where it can not find the image with proper tag.
When I added that tag manually pipeline passes.
deploying.yml
parameters:
  - name: pipelineOptions
    type: object
  - name: environment
    type: string
  - name: env
    type: string
  - name: region
    type: string
    default: $(region)

jobs:
  - template: cicd/deployment.yml@Pipelines
    parameters:
      pipelineOptions: ${{parameters.pipelineOptions}}
      environment: ${{parameters.environment}}

  - template: ./terraform/deploy.yml
    parameters:
      pipelineOptions: ${{parameters.pipelineOptions}}
      environment: ${{parameters.environment}}
      env: ${{parameters.env}}
      region: ${{parameters.region}}

/cicd/terraform/deploy.yml
parameters:
  - name: pipelineOptions
    type: object
  - name: environment
    type: string
  - name: region
    type: string
    default: $(region)
    [...]

jobs:
  - deployment: terraform_plan
      displayName: "Teraform Plan"
    environment: ${{parameters.environment}}
    workspace:
      clean: all
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
            [...]
            - task: TerraformCLI@0
              displayName: 'Terraform Plan'
              name: plan
              inputs:
                command: plan
                publishPlanResults: 'Terraform-Plan-${{parameters.env}}-$(System.StageAttempt)'
                workingDirectory: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/${{parameters.artifactName}}/terraform'
                commandOptions: '-out=$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/terraform/terraform.tfplan -detailed-exitcode'

Output from Terraform Plan step:

The pipelineID of resources pipeline is 379701 The runID of resources
pipeline is 379701 The runName of resources pipeline is 379701

Terraform Plan task:

379702 from registry: Got bad response from registry: 404 Not Found

EDIT 1.
I updated that part in deploy.yml like that:
- task: TerraformCLI@0
              displayName: 'Terraform Plan'
              name: plan
              inputs:
                command: plan
                publishPlanResults: 'Terraform-Plan-${{parameters.env}}-$(System.StageAttempt)'
                workingDirectory: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/${{parameters.artifactName}}/terraform'
                commandOptions: '-out=$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/terraform/terraform.tfplan -compact-warnings -detailed-exitcode -input=false -var-file=./config/$(projectId).tfvars -var="source_pipeline_runid=$(resources.pipeline.SourcePipeline.runID)"'

And added new variable in variables.tf, added reference to that variable in other .tf files.
variable "source_pipeline_runid" {
  description = "runID"
  type        = string
}


In DependantPipeline, if you set MainPipeline as a pipeline resource, you can use the predefined variable resources.pipeline.<Alias>.runID to get he buildId (runId) of MainPipeline.
For example, the YAML of DependantPipeline.
resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: mainPipe
    source: MainPipeline
    trigger:
    . . .

steps:
- script: |
    echo "Print the buildId/runId of pipeline resource."
    echo "resources.pipeline.mainPipe.runID = $(resources.pipeline.mainPipe.runID)"

For more available predefined variables, you can see "Pipeline resource variables".

EDIT:
From the YAML of DependantPipeline you provided, I can see you set the pipeline resource as below.
resources:
  . . .
  pipelines:
    - pipeline: MainPipeline
      project: DEV
      source: 'MainPipeline'
      trigger:
        branches:
          include:
            - neworder/pipeline

You define the alias of the pipeline resource as 'MainPipeline'. But, when you reference the predefined variable 'resources.pipeline.<Alias>.runID', you are using a wrong alias 'SourcePipeline' in the expression "$(resources.pipeline.SourcePipeline.runID)".
The correct expression should be "$(resources.pipeline.MainPipeline.runID)" that uses the right alias which is consistent with the one you defined on the pipeline resource.

EDIT_2:
Below is a sample to show to pass the runId as parameter into the nested templates.

The pipelines:

PipelineA: the main pipeline.
PipelineB: the dependant pipeline that will be triggered by PipelineA.


The main YAML of PipelineB.


# azure-pipelines.yml

resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: Pipelines
    type: git
    name: templatesYAML
    ref: main
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: mainPipe
    source: PipelineA
    trigger:
      branches:
        include:
        - main

extends:
  template: /cicd/pipeline.yml@Pipelines
  parameters:
    SourcePipeInfor:
      pipelineID: $(resources.pipeline.mainPipe.pipelineID)
      runID: $(resources.pipeline.mainPipe.runID)
      runName: $(resources.pipeline.mainPipe.runName)


The template YAML files.


The cicd/pipeline.yml.



# cicd/pipeline.yml

parameters:
- name: SourcePipeInfor
  type: object
  default: []

stages:
- template: /cicd/deploy_environments.yml@Pipelines
  parameters:
    SourcePipeInfor: ${{parameters.SourcePipeInfor}}


The cicd/deploy_environments.yml

# cicd/deploy_environments.yml

parameters:
- name: SourcePipeInfor
  type: object
  default: []

stages:
- stage: deploy
  jobs:
  - job: showInfor
    steps:
    - bash: |
        echo "The pipelineID of resources pipeline is ${{ parameters.SourcePipeInfor.pipelineID }}"
        echo "The runID of resources pipeline is ${{ parameters.SourcePipeInfor.runID }}"
        echo "The runName of resources pipeline is ${{ parameters.SourcePipeInfor.runName }}"
      displayName: 'Print resources pipeline information'


The result.




